# can i update subscription amount after subscribed in stripe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, stripe-payments

I am developing `rails application and integration of stripe payment`. I am new in stripe payment integration. I set up for plan to user subscribe. But i have 1 issue over here. Suppose, user subscribe for any one plan and all plan are recurring so every month deduct plan amount from customer account. Every plan have a some limit to add user in our site. If want to add extra user then pay $5 per user / month. which will be deduct every month with plan. Then now, how i can settle this amount with already subscribed plan to deduct extra use amount on every month.

Suppose, plan amount is $20 and extra user $5 per month. So, now set amount of plan $25 instead of $20 in recurring payment.

How can settle this amount or any other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this. First, you could create an [invoice item](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_invoiceitem) when you receive the `invoice.created` webhook from Stripe. This would let you add the $5 to the customer's upcoming invoice every month.

Second, you could create a new plan for the user and switch them to the new plan. There's no limit to the number of plans you can have in Stripe, so theoretically you could have unique plans for every customer.

That said, I would go with the first option if I were you. It's much simpler to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I solved issue. But right now i set `$1` for plan and now user subscribe for plan then set 20 quantity for that plan so deduct $20 for particular plan. Now if customer want to add extra user then i update quantity - `20 to 25 in particular customer subscription.` So now recurring amount become $25. `Problem solved.`